# Implement math functions in custom C# type?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Could someone point me to the interface that I need to implement in order to get basic math operators (i.e. +, -, *, /) to function on a custom type?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use [operator overloading.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28VS.71%29.aspx)

```
public struct YourClass
{
    public int Value;

   public static YourClass operator +(YourClass yc1, YourClass yc2) 
   {
      return new YourClass() { Value = yc1.Value + yc2.Value };
   }

}
```

Comment: In general, if you're doing operator overloading, you're probably dealing with what is a value type not a reference type that needs to (potentially) be a base clas for other types, so you should consider using a struct rather than a class for the underlying Type.

Comment: Charles, thanks for that suggestion I have had overlooked it. I edited the code.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static T operator *(T a, T b)
{
   // TODO
}
```

And so on for the other operators.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a good example of operator overloading for custom types [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28VS.71%29.aspx).

```
public struct Complex 
{
   public int real;
   public int imaginary;

   public Complex(int real, int imaginary) 
   {
      this.real = real;
      this.imaginary = imaginary;
   }

   // Declare which operator to overload (+), the types 
   // that can be added (two Complex objects), and the 
   // return type (Complex):
   public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2) 
   {
      return new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to overload the operators on the type.

```
// let user add matrices
    public static CustomType operator +(CustomType mat1, CustomType mat2)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is not an interface, but [Operator Overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28VS.71%29.aspx). Basically, you define a static method like so:

```
public static MyClass operator+(MyClass first, MyClass second)
{
    // This is where you combine first and second into a meaningful value.
}
```

after which you can add MyClasses together:

```
MyClass first = new MyClass();
MyClass second = new MyClass();
MyClass result = first + second;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the MSDN article on operators and overriding in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s53ehcz3(loband).aspx